# Trying to iterate over floats in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to complete this function but to no avail because the dictionary contains float values that I am trying to total up.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
def add_prices(basket):
    # Initialize the variable that will be used for the calculation
    total = 0
    # Iterate through the dictionary items
    for groceries, prices in basket.items():
        # Add each price to the total calculation
        for price in prices:
        # Hint: how do you access the values of
        # dictionary items?
            total += price.values()
    # Limit the return value to 2 decimal places
    return round(total, 2)
```

```py
groceries = {"bananas": 1.56, "apples": 2.50, "oranges": 0.99, "bread": 4.59, 
    "coffee": 6.99, "milk": 3.39, "eggs": 2.98, "cheese": 5.44}

print(add_prices(groceries)) # Should print 28.44
```

I'm completely dumbfounded tbh and need help, as tried typecasting to directly assigning the price to the values.

Comment: `total += price`: `price` is already a (float) value. Also remove the `for` line above it, since `prices` (rename it to `price`) is a single value.

Comment: Perhaps easier is to use sum: `return round(sum(basket.values()), 2)`: your function has become a one-liner.

Comment: When stuck on these positions, try printing at each step. I would suggest `print(groceries, prices)` in the first loop, and comment out everything else. I am sure you will be able to figure out what to add.

Comment: Hint: use `print` functions liberally for debugging purposes. E.g., `print(groceries)` and `print(prices)` directly below the first `for` line would be very helpful in getting insight in what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate over `prices`, as they are already `float` values. Hence the error message that floats are not iterable.

```
groceries = {"bananas": 1.56, "apples": 2.50, "oranges": 0.99, "bread": 4.59, "coffee": 6.99, "milk": 3.39, "eggs": 2.98, "cheese": 5.44}

def add_prices(basket):
    total = 0
    for groceries, prices in basket.items():
        total += prices
    return round(total, 2) 

add_prices(groceries)
#28.44
```

As also mentioned in the comments, it might be easier to change your function into a one-liner so you can avoid the for loop

```
def add_prices(basket):
    return round(sum(basket.values()), 2)
add_prices(groceries)
#28.44
```

Comment: thank you, for future reference how would one know when one needs to iterate over values in a dict

Comment: For a normal dict, you would only need to loop over the values if the values are stored within a list.

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily doing another loop. You can directly add the price.
Read about `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()`, `dict.items`.

It should be like

```py
def add_prices(basket):
    # Initialize the variable that will be used for the calculation
    total = 0
    # Iterate through the dictionary items
    for groceries, prices in basket.items():
        total += prices
        # Add each price to the total calculation
        #for price in prices:
        # Hint: how do you access the values of
        # dictionary items?
            #total += price.values()
    # Limit the return value to 2 decimal places
    return round(total, 2)
```

```py
print(add_prices(groceries)) 
>>> 28.44
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you did the second loop inside the main one when you can directly do this:

```
def add_prices(basket):
   # Initialize the variable that will be used for the calculation
   total = 0
   # Iterate through the dictionary items
   for groceries, prices in basket.items():
      total += prices
   # Limit the return value to 2 decimal places
   return round(total, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_prices(basket):
    # Initialize the variable that will be used for the calculation
    total = 0
    # Iterate through the dictionary items
    for  items in basket.values():
        
        total += items
    # Limit the return value to 2 decimal places
    return round(total, 2)  

groceries = {"bananas": 1.56, "apples": 2.50, "oranges": 0.99, "bread": 4.59, 
    "coffee": 6.99, "milk": 3.39, "eggs": 2.98, "cheese": 5.44}

print(add_prices(groceries)) # Should print 28.44
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Ways to Iterate Over a Dictionary

Suppose we have a dictionary

```
groceries = {"banana": 0.99, "milk": 3.99, "eggs": 2.99}
```

Here's how we can iterate over it

1. Iterate over the keys

```
for item in groceries:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
banana
milk
eggs
```

2. Iterate over the values

```
for price in groceries.values():
    print(price)
```

Result

```
0.99
3.99
2.99
```

3. Iterate over the key, value pairs

```
for item, price in groceries.items():
    print(item, price)
```

Result

```
banana, 0.99
milk, 3.99
eggs, 2.99
```

### When to Use Each Iteration Method

When I store data in a dictionary, I typically do it in such a way that it is most useful to iterate over the `(key, value)` pairs using [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items). In this case both the key and the value provide meaningful information and I want to use both during the iteration.

Groceries make sense as a dictionary because it seems reasonable to need both the `key`, i.e. the grocery item such as `banana`, and the `value`, i.e. the cost of the bananas. In this question, though you're just totaling the prices, regardless of what the item is. Thus, you don't need the keys, just the values.

If you just wanted to know the items on the grocery list then you would iterate over just the keys.